# Minimize cost of bundling updates (reverse knapsack?)

Tags: java, algorithm, pseudocode, knapsack-problem, greedy

For a school assignment I am to create Javacode for the following problem, I would like some tips and help on the pseudocode, **not the actual java code**. It has to be recursive. Personally, I think it's some kind of variation on the knapsack problem, or weighted interval scheduling. Anyways, this is the problem:

> A company behind an operating system supplies security updates via the
>   Internet. At a certain moment in time, a number of updates are in
>   development, and for each update the date when it is ready is known.
>
> Shipping an update incorporates a constant cost, equal for each
>   update, and variable cost, which can differ between updates.
>
> To minimize costs, the company is exploring the possibility of
>   bundling updates. A bundle is a series of updates that is shipped in
>   one go. The constant costs for a bundle is equal to the constant cost
>   of one update, but the variable costs of a bundle are defined as the
>   sum of the variable costs of the updates in it.
>
> Bundling updates can thus decrease the constant costs, but it also has
>   a drawback: postponing all security updates in a bundle until the
>   complete bundle is ready means users are longer at risk. This risk is
>   modelled as an extra cost. Essentially, there is a trade-off between
>   shipping an update directly (with a high sum of constant costs) or
>   postponing and shipping it in a bundle (with a high risk).
>
> Suppose the updates are sorted on the time when they are ready. Assume
>   that when an update is shipped, all updates that were ready earlier
>   are shipped also (in the same bundle or in an earlier bundle). The
>   company would like to know how to bundle updates, so that the total
>   costs of all bundles are minimized.

The following information is given:

> - a list of numbered security updates, sorted on the date when they are ready (the updates are indicated by 1,2,. . . ,)
> - the constant cost of shipping a bundle
> - for each update, the variable cost of shipping it
> - for each pair of updates, the cost of postponing all updates from the first update to the second update until the second update is shipped.

Comment: No christmas presents by SO this year... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about how to compute the minimum cost f(k) of sending out all updates 1 up to k.

This can be computed recursively, but make sure you memoize the results of the function calls or your complexity will become exponential.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I cant think of a way on how to compute the minimum cost f(k) recursively...

Comment: @heyitsme Consider how many updates will be in the last bundle.  If we knew there were x in the last bundle the cost will be f(k-x)+cost of bundling last x together.